# How to pass an argument that determines whether you add or remove a class from an element

Tags: javascript

I am calling a method that accepts a value, and that value then determines whether or not the classList is added or removed.

In the code below, if you pass "add" to the test method, it should add the classList, and if you pass "remove" it should remove it.

This code below doesn't work.

```
test (val) {
    const fileName = document.querySelector('.file-name')
    const fileSize = document.querySelector('.file-size')
    const updatedAt = document.querySelector('.uploaded-at')

    fileName.classList.val('line-through', 'text-gray-400')
    fileSize.classList.val('line-through', 'text-gray-400')
    updatedAt.classList.val('line-through', 'text-gray-400')
}
```

ex) test('remove') should remove the classList and test('add') should add it

Comment: the question is, how do I do this if it's possible lol

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: combine "if" statement with "add" and "remove" functions on classList

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) to access a property of an object evaluated as a result of an expression. In your particular case:

```js
fileName.classList[val]('line-through', 'text-gray-400')
fileSize.classList[val]('line-through', 'text-gray-400')
updatedAt.classList[val]('line-through', 'text-gray-400')
```

Comment: Nice this worked! He understood the assignment @Chris G

Answer (score 1):

Use the `toggle()` method, which accepts a boolean as an optional argument to specify whether to add or remove the class.

```
filename.classList.toggle('line-through', val == "add");
filename.classList.toggle('text-gray-400', val == "add");
```